# please explain this code for calculating hash code of a string

Tags: algorithm, string, hash, hashcode

I read an algorithm book which stated that the key of a given string is calculated as follows

```
 s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

using **int** arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

or in code:

```
 int h = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   h = 31*h + s.charAt(i);
 }
```

My question is that it seems the code implementation is not equivalent to the calculation method stated above.For example,given the string "ha" (ascii code 104 and 97 respectively)

s[0]*31^(2-1)+s[1]*31^0 = 104*31+97

from the code execution,the result is 104+31*104+97

absolutely the two are not equal,so how to explain this?

Reference Link: http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/node114.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're misreading the code.

After the first iteration, h is 104.

So the second iteration says:

```
h = 31 * 104 + 97;
```

... which is exactly what you were expecting.

It looks like you misread this line:

```
h = 31 * h + s.charAt(i);
```

as this:

```
h += 31 * h + s.charAt(i);
```

In the code that's given, we're not *adding* a new value to `h`, we're using simple assignment.

If you're actually written the code and seen the wrong value, check whether or not you've got "+=" instead of "=".

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
int p = 1, h = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    p *= 31;
    h += s.charAt(n - i - 1) * p;
}
```

for the code to be clear and as efficient as yours.

Your code uses [Horner's scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) and is correct, you should be able to understand it from the above wikipedia page.

Comment: What's `h` here? You haven't declared it. I think the code as posted is already correct, actually... the OP is just misreading it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: perhaps, I'm not really awake yet. There may be either an off by one or maybe `i` should be `n - i - 1` in OP's post. The code I give will work. I clarified my answer, and will check correctness of OP's code after breakfast.